How to Simulate a Signal with Known Gain and Phase to Validate Transfer Function Estimation?
I am trying to validate a method for estimating the Transfer Function between two signals by simulating a signal based on a real physiological signal.
My approach involves using a real signal of arterial blood pressure (ABP) and applying known Gain and Phase shifts in specific frequency ranges. Using the simulated output, I aim to check whether the Transfer Function, estimated by:
$$ H(f) = \frac{Pyx(f)}{Pxx(f)} $$

where $Pyx(f)$ is the cross-spectral density between the real and simulated signals, and
$Pxx(f)$ is the power spectral density (PSD) of the real signal (ABP)

correctly reproduces the input Gain and Phase values.
Code
First, I define a transfer function with known Gain and Phase for different frequency bands:
import numpy
import pandas
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft
from scipy.signal import csd, welch


def transfer_function(frequencies):
    gain = numpy.ones_like(frequencies)
    phase_shift = numpy.zeros_like(frequencies)

    gain[(frequencies >= 0.02) & (frequencies < 0.07)] = 0.8  # VLF
    phase_shift[(frequencies >= 0.02) & (frequencies < 0.07)] = -numpy.pi / 4  # VLF

    gain[(frequencies >= 0.07) & (frequencies < 0.2)] = 0.6  # LF
    phase_shift[(frequencies >= 0.07) & (frequencies < 0.2)] = -numpy.pi / 6  # LF

    gain[(frequencies >= 0.2) & (frequencies < 0.5)] = 0.4  # HF
    phase_shift[(frequencies >= 0.2) & (frequencies < 0.5)] = -numpy.pi / 8  # HF

    transfer_func = gain * numpy.exp(1j * phase_shift)
    return transfer_func

Next, I apply this transfer function to the real ABP signal, creating a simulated cerebral blood flow velocity (CBFV) signal:
abp_real = abp_real - abp_real.mean()
abp_fft = fft(abp_real)
frequencies = numpy.fft.fftfreq(len(abp_real), d=1/fs)

H_f = transfer_function(frequencies)
cbfv_fft = abp_fft * H_f
cbfv_simulated = numpy.real(ifft(cbfv_fft))

Transfer function estimation
I estimate the Transfer Function using the Welch method for PSD estimation:
def pwelch(abp, cbfv, fs):
    pxx = welch(abp, fs=fs, nperseg=256, nfft=1024)
    pyy = welch(cbfv, fs=fs, nperseg=256, nfft=1024)
    pxy = csd(abp, cbfv, fs=fs, nperseg=256, nfft=1024)
    return pxx[0], pxx[1], pxy[0], pxy[1], pyy[0], pyy[1]

f_xx, pxx, f_xy, pxy, f_yy, pyy = pwelch(abp_real, cbfv_simulated, fs=fs)
gain = pxy / pxx

vlf_indexes = band_indexes(f_xx, 0.02, 0.07)
gain_vlf = numpy.nanmean(abs(gain[vlf_indexes]))

lf_indexes = band_indexes(f_xx, 0.07, 0.2)
gain_lf = numpy.nanmean(abs(gain[lf_indexes]))

hf_indexes = band_indexes(f_xx, 0.2, 0.5)
gain_hf = numpy.nanmean(abs(gain[hf_indexes]))

Problem
I expected the estimated Gain values for VLF, LF, and HF bands to match the ones I used in transfer_function. However, I am getting:
Gain_VLF: 0.82815 (close to 0.8)
Gain_LF: 0.7641 (instead of 0.6)
Gain_HF: 0.69876 (instead of 0.4)

Question
How can I improve my signal simulation or the estimation method to ensure that the calculated Gain values for each frequency band (VLF, LF, HF) match the values used in the transfer_function?

abp_real isn't defined in the code you provided. Can you define it so I can run some tests? Also, are you sure your definition of $H(f)$ is the one you want? That definition holds in the case of a linear prediction framework (Wiener-Hopf). If you are referring to the transfer of a PSD through an asymptotically stable LTI system, that equation would be $\left\lvert H(\omega)\right\rvert^{2} = \frac{\phi_{yy}(\omega)}{\phi_{xx}(\omega)}$. The square root of this would be your gain, and the phase of the cross-spectral density would be your phase, I would think.

You also need to deal with negative frequencies in your transfer function generation…
